# If I use Gmail to send a message to multiple addresses and one of them returns a ''Address not found'' does it still send to the other addresses?

Tags: gmail

I sent an email by Gmail to:

aaa@bbb.com , ccc@ddd.com and eee@fff.com

Shortly afterwards I received an email saying that the address ccc@ddd.com was not found and to please check for typos or unnecessary spaces and try again.

It did not mention whether the email was sent successfully to the other addresses or not.

If one domain is not found does the email still get sent on to the other domains ?

Answer (score 2):

Only the undeliverable email will bounce, all valid recipients will receive the email.

You could verify this by sending an email to yourself + an invalid recipient.